# Unable to authenticate server even after including keystore certificate in SpringMVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, authentication, ssl

I am trying to authenticate to jira server and get issue details from the server given id here initially i am manually giving id.  i have downloaded the server certificate and imported using keytool and the password is "password" to keystore. but i am not able to authenticate to it below is my code

my java code :

```
@Controller
public class Service{


    @RequestMapping("/hello")


     public String Data(ModelMap model) throws KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException, FileNotFoundException, IOException, KeyManagementException, UnrecoverableKeyException{

        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        keyStore.load(new FileInputStream("/users/crohitk/Documents/workspace/frr/publicKey1.store"),
                "password".toCharArray());
        SSLConnectionSocketFactory socketFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(
                new SSLContextBuilder()
                        .loadTrustMaterial(null, new TrustSelfSignedStrategy())
                        .loadKeyMaterial(keyStore, "password".toCharArray()).build());
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(socketFactory).build();
        ClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(
                httpClient);
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(requestFactory);


        ResponseEntity<String> result = restTemplate.exchange("https://jira.example.com/",  HttpMethod.GET, new HttpEntity<String>(createHeaders("user", "password")), String.class);

        model.addAttribute("message", result);


        return "helloworld";

      }


     HttpHeaders createHeaders( String username, String password ){
        HttpHeaders header =  new HttpHeaders();
        String auth = username + ":" + password;
        byte[] encodedAuth = Base64.encodeBase64(auth.getBytes(Charset.forName("US-ASCII")) );
        String base64Creds = "Basic " + new String( encodedAuth );
        header.add("Authorization", "Basic " + base64Creds);
        return header;
    }   



}
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml :

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="frr.frr" />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

web.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">


    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>frr</groupId>
  <artifactId>frr</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>frr Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <properties>
        <spring.version>4.2.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>


<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
   <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
   <version>4.3.5</version>
</dependency>


        <dependency>
   <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
   <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
   <version>1.9</version>
</dependency>




  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>frr</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: i tried it on facebook also but i am not able to login it says incorrect email address

Comment: The code itself looks ok at first glance, but what about the "user/password" credentials being passed to the createHeader function? Is that a _valid JIra user_, or is it some copy-paste from somewhere? Jira clearly does not accept your authentication as a valid one, so the invalid login-info has to be the first suspect. So are you sure you are using a valid login?

Comment: yeah they are valid as i am using them to authenticate jira server here i replaced my credentials to user and password they are not the actual credentials

Comment: You have explicitly selected a charset when encoding (US-ASCII), but did not do the same when you converted this into String (new String( encodedAuth )). Is there any special default charset on your machine which required the first one?

Comment: For debugging purposes I would suggest to print the header-info from your program and use it from a Rest poster plugin (there are many for Firefox/Chrome) to see if your Jira accepts it.

Comment: no i have found that code on net for authentication so i am using it

Comment: can you give me any sample code that needs to authenticate jira like encoding and sending credentials in header  

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change encoding credentials of above code to below code in java file
there is some error in encoding of above code

```
HttpHeaders createHeaders(){
    String plainCreds = "user:password";
    byte[] plainCredsBytes = plainCreds.getBytes();
    byte[] base64CredsBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(plainCredsBytes);
    String base64Creds = new String(base64CredsBytes);


    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("Authorization", "Basic " + base64Creds);
    return headers;
}
```