# Spring Boot - Calling another web service that requires certificate

Tags: spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot rest service that would call another web service (written in .NET) but it requires a public certificate of that server where the web service is installed.

I am getting the following error:

```
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "https://domain.sample.com/api/message.asmx": sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Process finished with exit code -1
```

Not sure if you can call .asmx web service using RestTemplate though but this is my code:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.TEXT_XML);

HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(rawDeviceMessage, httpHeaders);

ResponseEntity<String> resultEntity = restTemplate.postForEntity("https://domain.sample.com/api/message.asmx", entity, String.class);
```

Comment: Did you add the .Net server's public key to your server's truststore? If your service doesn't use a trusted certificate you'll need to add it manually to your truststore.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exception unable to validate certificate of the target in spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32051596/exception-unable-to-validate-certificate-of-the-target-in-spring-mvc)

Comment: Hi @Mustafa, thank you for this. I will check this out and get back to you.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

As mentioned by @Mustafa in the comment section above, the following was a duplicate and the issue got resolved.

[Exception unable to validate certificate of the target in spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32051596/exception-unable-to-validate-certificate-of-the-target-in-spring-mvc)