# Create a SSL connection between spring and nodejs apps locally

Tags: java, node.js, spring, spring-boot, ssl

I have two apps, one is written in nodejs (which in this case is simple mock-server) and spring app (core app). I want to create a SSL connection between this two. Firstly I generated pair of key and cert, then simply setup a nodejs to work over SSL (I used this example: [setting SSL - nodeJs](https://hackernoon.com/set-up-ssl-in-nodejs-and-express-using-openssl-f2529eab5bb)). 
I have checked that when I wrote in browser https://localhost:3000 it gives me a "secure" connection (with open padlock - so it's ok).

Next I was making a configuration on spring app using [setting SSL - Spring](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-https-self-signed-certificate). I took a cert from previous step generation and set it in keystore into .p12 file. In spring application I changed the url to node app to https.

When I try to connect from spring app and get some mock data from node I'm getting this stacktrace:

`Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target`

I found something in [stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32051596/exception-unable-to-validate-certificate-of-the-target-in-spring-mvc) but when I set this cert in specific directory and then restart my app, result is same.

Have anyone maybe a clue what could be wrong in this configuration and some suggestion how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution of this problem. I don't know why, but when I created a keystore with cert inside and then use it in my spring app it cannot find this keystore with cert globally. I was looking for documentation about openJDK11 (because I used it) and find a link to [Enabling Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy](https://github.com/open-eid/cdoc4j/wiki/Enabling-Unlimited-Strength-Jurisdiction-Policy) and check file for which I have version of openJDK11.

In my case the line from `crypto.policy` was commented, don't know why. When I uncommented it and set `unlimited` it gives me one more error, but then I find one another solution. I found that, that I need to add my sign-self certificate to cacerts file ([how to add my self-signed cert to cacerts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11617210/how-to-properly-import-a-selfsigned-certificate-into-java-keystore-that-is-avail)). After this two operation it works as charm.